# How to call functions, which require the control `Parent` to be set, in constructor?

Tags: delphi, constructor, controls, access-violation

I have a `TCustomControl` and I must call in the constructor some functions which require that the control has the `Parent` property set. I tried to set it first and it's working if I create the instance of the control at run time but when I want to put it on the form at design time I get access violation. How can I fix this ?

```
constructor TPathHolder.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 Parent:=TWinControl(AOwner);

 //.....that function here.... 
end;
```

Comment: @kobik `csDesigning` is not the proper way to solve this issue. If parent is required then only proper place to put code that relies on parent is in `SetParent` method. Sometimes you cannot avoid having parent. For instance TComboBox control needs parent when you initialize its Items - both in design and run-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not assign Parent of control in your constructor (or in any part inside your control code). Setting parent inside control itself interferes with the way VCL framework works in both design and run-time.

Instead you can override SetParent method, and do your initialization there.

```
procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;

procedure TMyControl.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); 
begin
  inherited;
  // put custom initialization code here
end;
```

Just keep in mind that this method can be called multiple times during control lifetime, and passed AParent can be nil.

Comment: How does this change anything? Presumably the problems with setting Parent in the constructor remain. Or do you mean to stop setting Parent in the constructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If initialization is moved to `SetParent` method then line `Parent:=TWinControl(AOwner);` is not needed any more.

Comment: The answer doesn't state that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the reminder, it was obvious to me what OP wanted and I didn't provided sufficient explanation. Will edit answer later on to fully explain what happens here.

Answer (score 2):

You should not set the `Parent` in the constructor. It is as simple as that. The `Parent` should be set after the constructor has returned.

You will need to call these other functions, those that require `Parent` to be set, later. Or find a way to get the work done without requiring `Parent` to be set.

Comment: Setting parent inside control itself should never be done because it interferes with way VCL framework functions in both design and run-time.